# undefined reference to `WinMain@16', Trying to solve the twosum problem, but having problem running the code in my visual studio code IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
int main(){
   std::vector<int> nums = {3,2,3};
   int target= 6;
   Solution solution;
   std::vector<int> result = solution.twoSum(nums,target);
   // std::cout << result[0];
}

class Solution {
public:

std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    for (int i=0; i <= nums.size(); i++){
        for (int j=i+1; i <= nums.size(); i++){
            if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target){
                result.push_back(i);
                result.push_back(j);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return {};
}

};
```

Trying to solve the twosum problem, but having problem running the code in my visual studio code IDE. Why does it give this error:

```
[Running] cd "c:\projects\c++\" && g++ twoSum.cpp -o twoSum && "c:\projects\c++\"twoSum
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):
.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I don't get that far. Solution appears to be undefined when first used in `main`. When I flip the order, I cannot reproduce. Do you have the code separated in two files in your project? If so, have you instructed visual studio code to compile and link the file containing `main `?

Comment: Unrelated: a `<=` in a `for` loop's exit condition should always get a second look, and in this case the look says that the rages of `i` and `j` are off by one and `nums` is being accessed out of bounds.

Comment: Is this the first error encountered when compiling? Because this file shouldn't compile. You should never get to the linking stage.

Comment: There are duplicates for this behavior which you can add a linker switch to force a console application, however it may be helpful to show your `tasks.json`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Visual Studio expert, but this looks like you've selected the wrong Visual Studio project type. Your program is a simple console application, while a `WinMain` is required by graphical applications.

Comment: This is with mingw on Visual Studio Code which is a completely different product from Visual Studio Community, Pro or Enterprise.

Comment: @drescherjm AFAIK mingw is a kind of Unix environment on Windows, so the question might be, which compiler is called by VS-Code with which options regarding console app vs graphical app.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `main()` in your code but the linker can't find `WinMain()` then you're building the Windows GUI version (linker flag `-mwindows`) instead of the console version (linker flag `-mconsole`).

Check if your linker flags contain `-mwindows` and remove that and/or add the `-mconsole` linker flag.